# Before update event perform two actions

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger

Hi i have a situation here in before update event, i need to do two actions, one is to throw an error on record detail page and send an email to admin. But i am able to do only one action here. How to achieve this?

```
if(dupeOrder!=null && (dupeOrder.contains(ord.Name)||incomingDupeOrder.contains(ord.name))){ 
 SendEmailtoAdmin();            
ord.addError('There is already a Order number exists with same name-- contact admin ');
```

Comment: can you show what you have written in SendEmailtoAdmin() function

Comment: @salesforceDeveloper  i have written single email code.

Comment: I believe your error part is working and your Send email is not working, to know what you are doing in that function we need to check that

Comment: Also if you are not getting email please check your spam folder.

Comment: Call a future method and send email message from that.

Comment: @DVEL I have tried the future method, still it is not working.